# Jmeter Response Assertion is failing upon getting from Reg Ex Value

Tags: jmeter, response, assertion, text-extraction

Hello I have a scenario where I need to validate the extracted value  from my regex, unfortunately I'm encountering an error upon using Response Assertion. I would like to seek assistance to any one of you. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance

I am able to extract my regex upon running, but I encounter upon using that on my Response Assertion.

Screenshot:

[Response Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mHOZ.png)

[Response Assertion Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6c5y.png)

[Response Assertion Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUjcb.png)

Expected Result: I just want to validate "userId = 14534"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just check the presence of `14534` text in the response - just configure the Response Assertion as follows:

[image]

In case you want to check whether 1st row of the `user_id` column of your SQL query result set is equal to `14534`:

1. In the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler define a variable name, i.e. `user_id`

   [image]
2. Amend your Response Assertion configuration to Apply to a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) called `user_id_1`:

   [image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions)